# how to, hidden field value not showing up on request in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, post, request, zend-form, zend-form-element

i have a simple form that has a textarea ans a hidden field

```
    $textarea = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('post');
    $textarea->setRequired(true);
    $textarea->setLabel('');

    $hidden = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('post_id');
    $hidden->setLabel('');
    $hidden->setValue('1');      

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setLabel('test');

    $this->addElement($textarea);
    $this->addElement($hidden);
    $this->addElement($submit);

    $this->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
         array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form_class')),
        'Form'
    ));
```

in my view i do

```
<?php echo $this->form->getElement('post')->render(); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getElement('submit')->render(); ?>
```

then in my controller

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if( $request->isPost() && $form->isValid($request->getParams()))
    {
        Zend_Debug::dump($request->getParams());
    }
```

what happens is that i get

```
array(8) {
  ["module"] => string(6) "testr"
  ["controller"] => string(8) "posts"
  ["action"] => string(9) "post"
  ["post"] => string(10) "testgfdgfg"
  ["submit"] => string(26) "submit"
}
```

but no `post_id`

this is a bit wired and i cant figure it out. Ive looked for any code that might screw this up but nothing. I've also tried to echo the hidden field in the view, but i still get nothing on the request

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view do

```
<?php echo $this->form->getElement('post'); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getElement('post_id'); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getElement('submit');?>
```

You are simply not echoing post_id element like you did with post and submit . Also you don't need to call render() since php magic function __toString() proxy render() in all Zend_Form_Element_XXX .

Answer (score 1):

In View part you are just set two elements only

```
<?php echo $this->form->getElement('post')->render(); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->getElement('submit')->render(); ?>
```

WHERE form->getElement('post_id')->render(); ?>

```
 <?php echo $this->form->getElement('post')->render(); ?>
 <?php echo $this->form->getElement('submit')->render(); ?>
 <?php echo $this->form->getElement('post_id')->render(); ?>
```

Try once with this.

I think it will work.